# Query Log solo cuando la transacción ha sido satisfactoria

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Cómo podría implementar un query log solo cuando la transacción hace commit?

Intenté implementándolo en el appServiceProvider pero guarda las consultas que no fallan aún así falle la transacción.

Por ejemplo, tengo una transacción con 3 query's, el tercero falla y el logger guarda las 2 primeras.

Lo que busco solucionar es que no grabe nada si la transacción falla.

Esto es lo que tengo en el appServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function($query) {
            // Comprobar que la query no sea un SELECT
            $secciones = explode(' ', $query->sql);
            if ($secciones[0] !== 'select') {
                // Formatear sentencia SQL
                $msg = $query->sql.';';
                foreach($query->bindings AS $key => $value) {
                    if (is_string($value)) {
                        $msg = preg_replace('/\?/', '`'.$value.'`', $msg, 1);
                    } else {
                        $msg = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $msg, 1);
                    }
                }

                $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter("/* %datetime% */\t%message%\n");
                $stream = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/querys.log'), 5, \Monolog\Logger::INFO);
                $stream->setFormatter($formatter);
                $dbLog = new \Monolog\Logger('queryLog');
                $dbLog->pushHandler($stream);
                $dbLog->log('INFO', $msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: puedes poner algo de tu código?... nos costara saber cual es el problema si estamos a ciegas... ve a [ask] para mas informacion

Comment: Hola Victor Hugo, agregué el código que tengo, gracias